# Create dialog on click over layout

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog

I want to have something like this:

[image: dialog on click over layout of action bar]

When I click over my custom layout (formed by the layout title and some other layout things - see image), a small dialog appears below it with some other information (formed by the My Dialog and some dialog information - see image).

I have my custom layout placed on the action bar. I only need to create that dialog and show it in that place.

My custom action bar layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:focusable="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/llInformation">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="The layout title"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:id="@+id/tvLevel" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            ... here comes some other layout things

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And on my main activity code i have:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        ...//some other code
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer);

        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        LayoutInflater inflator = getLayoutInflater();
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.action_bar_layout, null);

        LinearLayout informationLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.llInformation);
        informationLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Code to call dialog
            }
        });

        actionBar.setCustomView(v);
    }
```

The only thing I am needing is the code to create and show that dialog the way the image shows.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a view in your layout file. Changing it to "visible" and "gone" as needed.